# Flutter async await http.post, status mismatch against backend

Tags: flutter, async-await

Can someone tell me why this function is not waiting for post request to finish?

```
static Future<bool> postOrderData(Order order, String token) async {
    try {
      final http.Response res = await http.post(baseUrl + "orders",
          headers: {
            HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: token
          },
          body: jsonEncode(order).toString());

      return res.statusCode == 201;
    } catch (ex) {
      print(ex);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

It is returning `false` - but from the logs of the backend i know that the call ended with status code 201.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: No exception - the consol log is empty

Comment: Can you put a print(res.statusCode); right before return res.statusCode == 201;

Comment: You are right. My error, when i print it everything is fine. So there must by another error somewhere in my code calling this function. Thank you verry much for your Help!